# Create a tag in AEM 6.1 using IE11 in touch UI mode

Tags: aem, tagging

I am attempting to use AEM 6.1's touch UI to create tags in Interner Explorer 11.
However after keying in values for all fields in the create tag dialog i.e. Title, Name and Description, I find the "Create Tag" button disabled.

Can anyone please point me to a reason or is it a known issue in AEM 6.1?

Comment: This turned out to be a product issue and a fix was provided by support team